# Hotmail vanishes any emails sent through Godaddy's SMTP

Tags: smtp, hotmail

Emails go through to Gmail or Yahoo fine but Hotmail it just swallows them, doesn't go to junk mail, no kick back or refusal, nothing, it just vanishes into the ether.

Is it possible to purchase SMTP relay access from a reputable provider that won't get flagged as spam? I just need a good stopgap solution as I haven't had this issue with a hosting provider before

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Use MailChimp or many other paid SMTP services. Some are API only, some will give you encrypted SMTP.